# Laravel environment specific package configuration

Tags: configuration, laravel-4

Laravel is pretty clear on how to set up [environment specific config](http://laravel.com/docs/configuration#environment-configuration).

It also has a method for creating [package configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/packages#package-configuration)

What I have not been able to find is an example of creating environment specific package configuration. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If your production app package config is here:

```
/app/config/packages/{name}/{package}/config.php
```

Then you just add an environment specific subfolder(s), same as you do for other configs:

```
/app/config/packages/{name}/{package}/local/config.php
/app/config/packages/{name}/{package}/testing/config.php
```

And just overwrite any production values with the specific environment variables you need.